# QT : no execution available

Tags: qt

I downloaded a free version of qt (5.6 5.7) with the tools and I made a card and when I want to compile I receive an error message that says:

> "Error compiling / deploying test project (kit: Desktop Qt 5.7.0
>   MSVC2015_64bit) When executing step "qmake"".

I tried downloading other tools, but I always get the same error.

Comment: Do you have MSVC2015 installed?

Comment: yes it is installed

Comment: Often that can mean that your kit has some errors, in Tools > Options > Build & Run > Kits